# Embedding Google Apps Script in an iFrame Error

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I'm trying to load a web app into an iframe in an external html file. I've built and tested the app and it works fine, stand alone. But when I load it into an iframe i get the following error..

"Exception: No HTML file named WebAppBoot was found. (line 2, file "Code")"

I modified the Code.gs to set the XFrameOptionsMode to allow all, like so...

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot');
  output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); 
}
```

I still get the same error

I used this tutorial as the starting point for my web app.. [Bootstrap Google Web Application Form](https://codewithcurt.com/create-a-bootstrap-web-app-form-on-google-sheets-using-apps-script/) Take a look at it to see the file structure in the google "Project", its exactly the same as my web app

Comment: I think that in your script, the function is finished at the 1st line of `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot.html');`. So `output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);` is not used. How about this? If you want to use this, when you modify it to `function doGet(e) {return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot.html').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)}`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I get the same result. I can't tell if the web app is loading into the iframe or not. It seems like it may be because when i test it in a browser i see a "Google Apps Script" message saying that it can't find the html file that's included in the "Google Project". It looks like the Code.gs file is executing inside of the iframe, otherwise it wouldn't display the error that the app is missing the WebAppBoot.html file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: What are the names of the .html files in your Apps script project?

Comment: In the Apps Script Project there are only two files Code.gs and WebAppBoot.html

Comment: Please add the steps that you followed to publish your web application including the version that is published and if you used the old IDE or the new IDE. By the way the last line of doGet function in the question will never be executed because it's after the `return` statement.

Comment: Using the old IDE. Publish > Deploy As Web App > Project Version "1" > Execute App As: "Me" > Who Has Access To The App: "Anyone"

Comment: Save a new version and try again.

Comment: Could you help me append the "XFramesOptionMode.ALLOWALL" to the doGet function as well? I just republished it but i'm sure it won't load if i don't have this right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` of line 2, and `output` from line 3

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); 
}
```

then publish again your web app creating a new version (on the version dropdown, select New)

Every time that you made a change to your code that want to see on the /exec web app URL you have to publish again your web creating a new version.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot');
  output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); 
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, I changed 'WebAppBoot.html'..to..'WebAppBoot. But i get the same error message. It seems like the Code.gs script is successfully executing inside of the iframe otherwise it wouldn't display such a specific error - looking for a specific file .."Exception: No HTML file named WebAppBoot was found. (line 2, file "Code")"... Do you think that at least the first half of this mystery is solved? That the script is successfully executing in the iframe?